# Groupby for nested rows in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good morning guys,

I have the following dataframe:

```
   Owner       Areas  Title    DNS
0  Brian  Production  MacOS  libre
1  Brian     Testing     MS  noapp
2   Andy         Uat   Unix   high
3   Paul    Research  Linux  lowhw
```

Generated by the first print. ( print(df) )

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'Owner':['Brian','Brian','Andy','Paul'],
    'Areas':['Production','Testing','Uat','Research'],
    'Title':['MacOS','MS','Unix','Linux'],
    'DNS':['libre','noapp','high','lowhw']
    })
print(df)

result = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Owner','Areas','Title','DNS'])['Title'].count())
print(result)
```

The new df called result should look like this:

```
        Count_of_title
Andy        3
Uat         1
Unix        1
high        1

Brian       6

 Production 1
 MacOS      1
 libre      1

 Testing    1
 Ms         1
 noapp      1

Paul        3 
Research    1
Linux       1
lowhw       1

Grand total 12
```

But I get:

```
                              Title
Owner Areas      Title DNS
Andy  Uat        Unix  high       1
Brian Production MacOS libre      1
      Testing    MS    noapp      1
Paul  Research   Linux lowhw      1
```

What I would like to achieve is to calculate for each Owner how many Areas&Title&DNS has and write that value after his name (Count_of_title column). The "Grand Total" calculates 3 (from Andy) + 6 (from Brian) + 3 (from Paul)= 12. 
Is this possible? I tried with pivot_table/pivot as well, but I've got no luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you are looking for

```
new_df = df.groupby('Owner').agg({'Areas': 'nunique', 'Title': 'nunique', 'DNS': 'nunique'})
```

Total per Owner:

```
new_df['Total'] = new_df['Areas'] + new_df['Title'] + new_df['DNS']
```

Output:

```
    Areas Title DNS Total
Owner               
Andy    1   1   1   3
Brian   2   2   2   6
Paul    1   1   1   3
```

Grand Total:

```
Grand_Total = sum(new_df['Total'])
```